# Retrieve -Azure RMS Summary- report using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, reporting

I need to automate the generation of an e-mail that contains the data from the **Azure RMS Summary** report from one of our tenants.

The Azure Reporting API does not contain this report as one of the possibilities to retrieve the data from.

I even tried an Invoke Web-Request from PowerShell to see if I could just pull out the webpage and then parse it to retrieve the data but the Azure security features won't let the page load from a PowerShell request.

Is there a way to retrieve this data using PowerShell?

[image: Report Generated from Browser]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Azure RMS Logs and downloading those to a Database for report generation?  I use PowerShell, SQL and Power BI to generate my reports.

Pull the log with
`Get-AadrmUserLog -Path D:\RMSLogs\Oct -fromdate 10/1/2016 –todate 10/30/2016`

Use Log Parser 2.2 to send it to SQL

```
logparser.exe -i:W3C -o:SQL -server:localhost -database:RMSReporting -username:SQLUser -password:Password -createTable:ON -driver:"SQL Server Native Client 11.0" -q:ON "SELECT * INTO RMS FROM D:\rmslogs\Oct\*.log" -transactionRowCount:-1
```

And now you can use your favorite report generator to show the numbers.  This also allows you to view which templates are being used and by who.

Be aware the log files can get very large.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately I need to retrieve exactly the report as it is shown in the page.  That is the business requirement.

It seems that MS hasn't made it available from PS.